# I have a program that connects to a data stream. How can I control it to only operate from Sunday 5pm to Friday 5pm each week?

Tags: python-3.x

So, Im creating a program to use with my broker's API, I connect to a trade stream and get data constantly.

Sicne the Forex market is closed from Friday 5pm to Sunday 5pm, I need my program to stop streaming data during this time.

I've tried many things, but I am unsure what way it right.

At the moment, the most logical way was to create a secondary file that controlled the time and date. It works for the first set (turning on the program at a certain time) but will not turn off because the first program is in the middle of a loop. Once I close the loop, the second program springs into action.

Here is a very simple concept program just to give you an idea of what I'm going for.

```
import datetime
import time
import os

friday = 4
fri_time = datetime.time(16,55)

sunday = 6
sun_time = datetime.time(17,05)

if datetime.date.today().weekday() == sunday:
    if datetime.datetime.now().time() >= sun_time:
        print('market is now open')
        os.system(r'C:\Users\clay\Desktop\MyPy\broker\App_V2.0.py')
else:
    pass


if datetime.date.today().weekday() == friday:
    if datetime.datetime.now().time() >= fri_time:
        print('market is now closed')
        os.system('taskkill /f /im App_V2.0.py')

else:
    pass
```

I've also tried adding it to the program itself but no matter what I am having a hard time controlling the program after it starts its loop. It only wants to kill the program after the loop has completed (or been closed manually)

How can you force terminate a loop controlled by time?

What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: *"I need my program to stop streaming data during this time"* - why? Does it not get data? Does it get duplicated data? Maybe they are the things you should be checking for, rather than the time?

Comment: Checkout the `sched` module on the python standard.

Comment: Thanks Rolando, I will check it out now. Jon, I'm trying to take you serious but that just sounds really condescending. Everyone has to start somewhere. The data produced doesn't provide any type of indicator that the market is closed, no duplicate data, no updates, no nothing. If my program tries to trade, it throws an error because it can't trade when market hours are off. I'd say Yes maybe I can detect when the data slows down but at the same time, there are times when the data doesn't update for 5 minutes, so that would be half assin' it lol :P.